# React style grid row on condition

Tags: reactjs, styling, react-data-grid

I'm using React Data Grid (https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/) to display data.
Everything works fine, but I would like to add custom styling (change background color) to a particular row if a value like 25 is between `minNumberOfUsers` and  `maxNumberOfUsers` as example.
I have a value like 25 users for this customer.
Now I want to see what current tier this customer is in!
I want to do that by coloring its `tr` background.
`minNumberOfUsers` has as example 10  and `maxNumberOfUsers` has 15 in the first row!
`minNumberOfUsers` has as example 20  and `maxNumberOfUsers` has 30 in the second row!
In that case I want the second row in another color because 25 is between 20 and 30 in the second row!
This is what I have now:

```
<Grid
  rows={this.state.fields.priceplan.userPriceTiers || []}
  columns={[
    { name: "minNumberOfUsers", title: "minNumberOfUsers },
    { name: "maxNumberOfUsers", title: "maxNumberOfUsers" },
    { name: "price", title: "priceuser" },
]}>
<CurrencyTypeProvider for={["price"]} />
<NumberTypeProvider for={["minNumberOfUsers", "maxNumberOfUsers"]} />
<Table columnExtensions={[{ columnName: "minNumberOfUsers", width: 150 }, { columnName: "maxNumberOfUsers", width: 150 }]} />
<TableHeaderRow />
</Grid>
```

Does anyone know how to add custom classnames or styling to a `tr` when a value is between a value in the column grid?
I need this to show the current pricetier of users their in.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

The above tier is colored yellow because I have 25 users and 25 is between 1 and 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `rowComponent` prop in the `<Table>` element which accepts another React Component

```
const TableRow = (props) => (   
const valueToCheck = "25";
<Table.Row {...props}
    style={
      (valueToCheck>=props.row.minNumberOfUsers && valueToCheck<=props.row.minNumberOfUsers)?({backgroundColor: "yellow"}:({}))
    }   /> );
```

In this component, you can define custom styling for the rows in the style attribute.

You can read more about this in the row subheading of this [url](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/fundamentals/)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `Binding element 'row' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: @Jbadminton Try this

```const TableRow = (props) => (   
const valueToCheck = "25";
<Table.Row {...props}
    style={
      (valueToCheck>=props.row.minNumberOfUsers && valueToCheck<=props.row.minNumberOfUsers)?({backgroundColor: "yellow"}:({}))
    }   /> );
```

Comment: Thanks! Please update your answer with it! You deserve the bounty ;)

Answer (score 0):

or you can **wrap the grid in the div with your CSS className** and then in your CSS do: **.my-class-name .react-data-grid {}**... and then you don´t have to use !important (it is better with LESS or SASS as you don´t have to type .some-class everytime). Here is similar issue  [enter link description here](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/674)

```
<div className="custom-style">
     <Grid>
</div>
```

and in the css

```
.custom-style.react-data-grid {--------style-------}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, I need to style a certain `tr` by give it a classname